# Screen page is getting switch but not showing bar-charts in the next screen in android

Tags: android, bar-chart

I cannot able to show the bar-charts on the next screen.Here i am using achartengine for creating a bar chart.And i didn't get any errors on the log-cat too.Suggestions please!..

Thanks for your precious time!..

*Please find my sources for reference*

**Chart_MainActivity.java**

```
public class Chart_MainActivity extends Activity 
{   
Button btn;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_invoke);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Intent int_obj = new Intent(Chart_MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(int_obj);
        }
    });   }}
```

**NextActivity.java**

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity 
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);
    createIntent();
 /*     
    Intent intent = createIntent();
    startActivity(intent);
 */
}   

public void createIntent()
{       
    String[] titles = new String[] { "Order's profit of the year", " " };

    List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();

    values.add(new double[] { 7, 2, 5, 8 });
    values.add(new double[] {});

    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.WHITE};

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
    renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

setChartSettings(renderer, "Profit for the year 2012", " ", " ",0,10, 0,10, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);

    renderer.setXLabels(1);
    renderer.addXTextLabel(0.75, "ord1");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(1.75, "ord2");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(2.75, "ord3");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(3.75, "ord4");
    renderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);

    int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{
    SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
    seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    }
ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(this, buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer,Type.DEFAULT);
    }

 protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) 
 {  

    // creates a SeriesRenderer and initializes it with useful default values as well as colors

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(15);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);

    int length = colors.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
       SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
       r.setColor(colors[i]);
       renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
       }
    return renderer;
    }

protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String title, String xTitle,
    String yTitle, double xMin, double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,int labelsColor) 
    {
        // sets lots of default values for this renderer

        renderer.setChartTitle(title);
        renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
        renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);

        renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
        renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);

        renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
        renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);

        renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
        renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);

        renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
      }

protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titles, List<double[]> values) 
{   
  // adds the axis titles and values into the data-set

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    int length = titles.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
       CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(titles[i]);
       double[] v = values.get(i);
       int seriesLength = v.length;

       for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) 
       {
          series.add(v[k]);
        }
       dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
      }

      return dataset;
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.barchart_test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8" android:maxSdkVersion="15"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity   android:name=".Chart_MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_chart__main" >
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
       </activity>
    <activity android:name=".NextActivity"></activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you need to fix ur manifest xml and add intent to the .Nexy activity activity

```
<activity android:name=".NextActivity">
<intent-filter>  
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.next_activity" />  
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
</activity>
```